# Convert png to jpeg using scikit-image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm new to scikit-image and image processing and trying to convert png image to jpeg. But my misfortune was that I couldn't find a way nor documentation. I want to convert it only using scikit, I have already tried pillow and succeed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `skimage.io.imread()` and `skimage.io.imsave()` and specify which plugin to use ...

Comment: I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear to me why exactly you are asking this or what are you trying to achieve but but as far as I know scikit uses plugins to read and write images. Check [this page](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html) that provides a summary of the available plugins for example.

You can check the plugin available using:

```
import skimage.io as io
io.find_available_plugins()
```

(in my case)

> {'fits': ['imread', 'imread_collection'],  'gdal': ['imread',
>   'imread_collection'],  'gtk': ['imshow'],  'imageio': ['imread',
>   'imsave', 'imread_collection'],  'imread': ['imread', 'imsave',
>   'imread_collection'],  'matplotlib': ['imshow', 'imread',
>   'imshow_collection', 'imread_collection'],  'pil': ['imread',
>   'imsave', 'imread_collection'],  'qt': ['imshow', 'imsave', 'imread',
>   'imread_collection'],  'simpleitk': ['imread', 'imsave',
>   'imread_collection'],  'tifffile': ['imread', 'imsave',
>   'imread_collection']}

and the loaded ones with:

```
io.find_available_plugins(loaded=True)
```

(in my case)

> {'matplotlib': ['imshow', 'imread', 'imshow_collection',
>   'imread_collection'],  'pil': ['imread', 'imsave',
>   'imread_collection']}

You can load a plugin:

```
import skimage.io as io
io.use_plugin('pil')
```

or a specific module:

```
io.use_plugin('pil', 'imread') # Use only the imread capability of PIL
```

So, you can choose which plugin to use. In either case it's not pure skikit of course.
Extended information can be found [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/plugins.html) (most commands where taken from here).

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot!